# How to add application manifest for ClickOnce applications

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have a Winforms application (C# - .NET 4.5.2) integrated with CefSharp.WinForms nuget package.
It is deployed using ClickOnce.

It works well, but I have an issue with tooltips.
The issue is exactly this: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1328

The proposed solution is to ad an application.manifest file, and I did it.

Unfortunately I get this build error now:

> 16>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3797,5):
>   error MSB3113: Could not find file 'Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=*, PublicKeyToken=6595b64144ccf1df,
>   ProcessorArchitecture=*, Type=win32'.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Posting the answer for future reference:

When providing a custom application manifest, you **have to** disable `ClickOnce` security from

> Project Properties -> Security Tab -> "Enable ClickOnce security settings" checkbox